# Webdriver io cucumber test fails to run with invalid argument error

Tags: timeout, invalid-argument

I am new to webdriver io. I ran my cucumber test and it fails with this error

```
`[0-0] 2023-02-14T21:47:36.064Z WARN webdriver: Request failed with status 400 due to invalid argument: unrecognized capability: pollTimeout
[0-0] 2023-02-14T21:47:36.065Z INFO webdriver: Retrying 1/3
[0-0] 2023-02-14T21:47:36.066Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:9515/session
[0-0] 2023-02-14T21:47:36.066Z INFO webdriver: DATA {
[0-0]   capabilities: {
[0-0]     alwaysMatch: {
[0-0]       browserName: 'chrome',
[0-0]       acceptInsecureCerts: true,
[0-0]       pollTimeout: 10000
[0-0]     },
[0-0]     firstMatch: [ {} ]
[0-0]   },
[0-0]   desiredCapabilities: {
[0-0]     browserName: 'chrome',
[0-0]     acceptInsecureCerts: true,
[0-0]     pollTimeout: 10000
[0-0]   }
[0-0] }`
```

Any suggesion on how i can resolve this please?

i tried to comment out waitforTimeout: 10000, in wdio.config.js but it doesnt solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem for myself. I uninstall node and install them with brew to the next version (19.6.0).
After that - 500. Because, chromedriver don`t support Chrome. After that, I updated Google chrome and everything worked.

Comment: Dmitriy U, I have upgraded my node js version and also upgrade chrome browser version, I still get the same result

Answer (score 0):

I install new node version and re-init the wdio, now it work.